# Casting Error with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I have an application that uses plugins that are managed via an interface I then dynamically load the plugin classes and cast them to the interface to work with them.

I have the following line of code, assume that IPlugin is my interface.

```
IPlugin _plugin = (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(oInfo.Assembly, oInfo.FullyQualifiedName)
```

This should be pretty simple, create the instance and cast it to the interface.  I know that the assembly and fully qualified name values are correct, but I am getting the following exception.

> Exception=
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to
>   cast object of type
>   ‘System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle’
>   to type
>   ‘MyNamespace.Components.Integration.IPlugin’.
>   at
>   MyNamespace.Components.Integration.PluginProxy..ctor(Int32
>   instanceId)

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exception indicates that you're getting an `ObjectHandle`, which suggests that your object is being marshaled and must be unwrapped.

Try the following

```
ObjectHandle marshaled_plugin = (ObjectHandle)Activator.CreateInstance(oInfo.Assembly,  Info.FullyQualifiedName);
IPlugin plugin = (IPlugin)marshaled_plugin.Unwrap();
```

Answer (score 7):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx), this overload returns an [`ObjectHandle` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.aspx) that wraps the new instance.

The `ObjectHandle` cannot be casted directly to your interface.
Instead, you need to call the [`Unwrap` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.unwrap.aspx), like this:

```
IPlugin _plugin = (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(...).Unwrap();
```

Comment: Won't he need to cast to `ObjectHandle` first, in order to `Unwrap()`?

Comment: @Jay: No; it's declared as returning `ObjectHandle`.  Read the documentation.